# SwiftUI 2.0: Clicking on MapAnnotation does nothing

Tags: xcode, swiftui

Im using the `Xcode 12.0 Beta` (tried with both Beta 3 and 4) and `SwiftUI 2.0`. I am using the new `Map` view:

```
struct MapContainer: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var store: AppStore
  
  func select() {
    print("Hello World")
  }
  
  
  var body: some View {
    return Group {
      if store.state.search.results.count > 0 {
      Map(
      coordinateRegion: $store.state.search.near.region,
      interactionModes: .all,
      showsUserLocation: true,
      annotationItems: store.state.search.results,
      annotationContent: { place in
        MapAnnotation(coordinate: place.coordinates) {
          ZStack {
            Button(action: select) {
              Circle().fill(Color.red).frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            }
          }
        }
      }
    )
  }
    }
  }
}
```

However, when I click the annotations on first load nothing happens, but if a navigate to another view and navigate back, then clicking on the annotations prints "Hello World" as expected. However, if I pan the map and then try to click an annotation, the annotation goes back to doing nothing until I navigate away and back.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Looks like SwiftUI bug - submit feedback to Apple.

Comment: I posted a response to this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63211092/how-do-i-make-a-clickable-pin-in-swiftuis-new-map-view/63438880#63438880)